# Can I use the requests lib to read the content of a 404 page?

Tags: python, python-requests

When I use the requests lib, it comes out with only status code 404.
*Like this:*`<Response [404]>`
But in fact, there's something in the 404 page:

> 404 Not Found
> 這個作品ID中有只有 12 張圖片，請指定正確的頁數，請參考首頁說明。

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('404 URL')
if response.status_code == 404:
  print(response.text) # Prints the raw 404 HTML response data
```

Answer (score 0):

Response object has other attributes as well apart from status. Use dir(response_obj) for other check all attributes of the object and response.text() should give you the text message also.